# Webpack and typescript don't work

Tags: typescript, webpack

I want to start my webpack project using typescript 1.8.10 but when I type `webpack-dev-server --port 3001`, webpack seems to be shutting down with no error message.

Here's the output from the console window:

```
E:\Files\Document\Project>webpack-dev-server --port 3001
http://localhost:3001/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from E:\Files\Document\Project
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and E:\Files\Document\Project\tsconfig.json
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: navigate to http://localhost:3001/webpack-dev-server/

Answer (score 0):

> webpack seems to be shutting down with no error message.

I doubt it.

Run `curl http://127.0.0.0.1:3001` and see the output.